# dataframe take value of previous row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks as follows:

```
idx  prev_val  val  type
 0      nan     8    a
 1      nan     9    a
 2      nan     7    a
 0      nan     3    b
 1      nan     1    b
 0      nan     2    c
 1      nan     7    c
 2      nan     5    c
 3      nan     4    c
```

I want that, per type, for each row that idx > 0, the value of `prev_val` will be taken from `val` of the previous row. So, the new dataframe will be:

```
idx  prev_val  val  type
 0      nan     8    a
 1       8      9    a
 2       9      7    a
 0      nan     3    b
 1       3      1    b
 0      nan     2    c
 1       2      7    c
 2       7      5    c
 3       5      4    c
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: shouldn't row `0       1      2    c` in your output be `0       nan      2    c` as idx is 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so using `groupby` and `shift`

```
df['prev_val'] = df.groupby('type')['val'].shift()

0   0      NaN   8    a
1   1        8   9    a
2   2        9   7    a
3   0      NaN   3    b
4   1        3   1    b
5   0      NaN   2    c
6   1        2   7    c
7   2        7   5    c
8   3        5   4    c
```

Note as @jezrael mentioned this solution works if each group starts with idx = 0.

Comment: The output doesn't match to the one desired by OP

Comment: Depends on datatype of column right? from his example I assumed its `str` ('nan' vs 'NaN'). However I've removed it for now.

Answer (score 1):

you could try with `np.where`:

```
df['prev_val']=np.where(df['idx']!=0, df.val.shift(),np.nan)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `type` + `shift` the column `val`, then assign the value to the column `prev_val` using `boolean indexing`:

```
df.loc[df['idx'].gt(0), 'prev_val'] = df.groupby('type')['val'].shift()
```

Result:

```
   idx  prev_val  val type
0    0       NaN    8    a
1    1       8.0    9    a
2    2       9.0    7    a
3    0       NaN    3    b
4    1       3.0    1    b
5    0       NaN    2    c
6    1       2.0    7    c
7    2       7.0    5    c
8    3       5.0    4    c
```

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Can you specify why this answer is better than Scoot's answer?

Comment: @okuoub Didn't you specify the condition that `I want that, per type, for each row that **idx > 0**, the value of prev_val will be taken from val of the previous row.`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Yep but it also the case in this answer, but a bit more genric as it keep the 1st element per group without specify it is 0

Comment: @okuoub i see. well i have written the answer keeping condition you presented in mind. I supposed that idx are not always ordered and can contain any value.

Answer (score 0):

Best would be to use Pandas fillna function like this:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

```
df.fillna(method='ffill')
```